# Arc length function of a helix/spiral is convex?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations

Given the arc-length of a parametric curve, $\int_a^b\|\gamma'(t)\|$ if the parametric curve was non-convex, can the arc length be a convex function?If the parametric curve was convex, will the arc length be a convex function? Is there any definite relationship..

For the toroidal spiral curve parametrized by:
$$x(t) = (a + b \cos(qt)) \cos (pt)$$
$$y(t) = (a + b \cos (qt)) \sin (pt)$$
$$z(t) = b \sin (qt) $$

is the arc-length function convex in t? Does it depend on the choice of a,b,p and q?

Comment: These are unrelated

Comment: Ok. For the specific parametric curve of the toroidal spiral, that I added in, can you comment on the convexity of the arc length function as well? Thanks.

Comment: what should convexity in context of vector valued functions mean?

Comment: The conditions for convexity of vector-valued functions that you ask for are in eqns 592, 595 of https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~dattorro/gcf.pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that an arbitrary regular curve $\gamma$ can be parametrized by arc length, there's no hope of deducing convexity of the arc length function
$$
s(t) = \int_{a}^{t} \|\gamma'\|
$$
from the shape of the curve. Convexity of the arc length function depends entirely on the parametrization.

In particular, convexity of a curve can have no bearing on convexity of the arc length function, just as Hagen von Eitzen noted.

If $p/q$ is rational (and both $p$ and $q$ are non-zero), the arc length of the toroidal spiral is neither concave nor convex because the speed is periodic and not constant. By a continuity argument, I believe you can make the same deduction for arbitrary non-zero $p$ and $q$. (If $p$ or $q$ is zero, the speed is obviously constant and the arc length is proportional to $t$.)